# Custom User Role with Providers (Google, FB, Email)

Tags: authentication, strapi, user-roles

I have Strapi V4 and 2 custom user roles - seller and buyer.

On the front-end, I have 2 routes that define which role will be assigned to new users `/account-buyer/signin` and `/account-seller/signin`.

I tried to make a copy from `node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\server\controllers\auth.js` to `src\extensions\users-permissions\controllers\auth.js`. but nothing seems to happen.

Also, I’m not sure how to throw the user type (buyer/seller) through all of these back-and-forth redirects of Google (for example).

How could I solve it?

Or let’s say:

1. save the needed role in localstorage at the moment the provider button is clicked
2. register the user with the default `Authenticated` role
3. on the frontend's `/redirect` page read the value that has to be set.
4. Send the value from localstorage and reassign user's role

How can I update the user’s role in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with setting up the Google auth flow with your frontend and Strapi first. On sign in for a non-existing user this will register a user with the default role. Depending on your frontend authentication framework you can pass arguments to the redirect url, e.g. `/api/user-registered?role=<some-role>&redirect=<original-redirect-url>` (this route can also exist within Strapi instead of your frontend). On this page I would call the Strapi API (or e.g. query engine API inside Strapi itself) and update the role of the current user (you know who this is because they just signed in).